# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\my booking.php on line 158

Tags: php, html, arrays, error-handling, warnings

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\my booking.php on line 158

The error is `$b = count($service);` on the 158 line.

```
$b = count($service);
```

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure that the value of `$service` is an `array` or an object implementing the `Countable` interface, as the error message says.

Comment: Whatever `$service` is, it isn't something where you can except that counting makes sense. For instance, imagine it's `null` or `false`. What should `count(null)` or `count(false)` be?

Comment: For the question we'd need result of `var_dump($service)`. For code you could use ternary to first check it is iterable. maybe `$b = !empty($service) ? count($service) : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

The `count()` function requires as parameter an array or object, so make sure your `$service` is an array or object. You can check this with `echo gettype($service)`;

If you want to get the length of a string, use `strlen($myString);`.

It would help a lot if you provide us the result of `var_dump($service)`.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

if(is_countable($service))$service = Array();

I got the same problem and I created empty array.
works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
if(is_array($service) || is_object($service)){$b = count($service);}
```